# Deploying django project getting no result

Tags: django, apache, web-deployment

have googled quite a bit now and followed the django documentation.. Still won't work but I think I'm pretty close.. I know there are lots of information about this around but even tho  I've tried a few guides it still won't work and I think I have tested most stuff that are suggested in other topics..

I'm trying to deploy my django site at my server, that is working in development mode (from the shell). So when running python manage.py runserver it's fine, but when trying to get an apache2 server to run django, first I got "The requested URL / was not found on this server.", now I get in the error.log of apache:

```
[client 192.168.1.49] mod_wsgi (pid=5606): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server/Server/wsgi.py'.
[client 192.168.1.49] Traceback (most recent call last):
[client 192.168.1.49]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
[client 192.168.1.49]     self.load_middleware()
[client 192.168.1.49]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
[client 192.168.1.49]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[client 192.168.1.49]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
[client 192.168.1.49]     self._setup(name)
[client 192.168.1.49]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
[client 192.168.1.49]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[client 192.168.1.49]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
[client 192.168.1.49]     raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
[client 192.168.1.49] ImportError: Could not import settings 'Server.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named Server.settings
```

So I have installed all things mentioned in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/

Well first of all I have my site located at: /home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server

(The name of the site is Server..) So here's the template, static and media folder along with the app dataManager that is doing most of the work.
In the folder /home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server/Server we find:

**django.wsgi:** (This file I had to manually create, don't know if that worked alright..)

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Server.settings")

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**wsgi.py:** (From this file I can write error messages, so this file is running (!))

```
import sys, os
print  >>sys.stderr, "hej from wsgi.py"
sys.path.append('/home/Wedmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Server.settings")

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler( )
```

**settings.py:**

```
import warnings
import exceptions
# PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=exceptions.RuntimeWarning,  module='django.db.backends.sqlite3', lineno=50)

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '/home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server/Server/db/database',  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Stockholm'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server/media' 

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 755

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server/static'  

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server/static/',
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin_media/'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    #'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Server.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Server.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server/templates',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'dataManager',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django_evolution',
)

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Then I have tried two versions of the **https.conf** in /etc/apache2:

```
Alias /static/ /home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server/static/

<Directory /home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server/static>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server/Server/django.wsgi

<Directory /usr/local/django/mysite/apache>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**Second test:**

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server/Server/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django
<Location "/Server">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE Server.settings
    PythonOption django.root /Server
    PythonPath "['/home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/',     '/home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server','/home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server/dataManager', '/home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/'] + sys.path"
    PythonDebug On
</Location>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/django.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server/Server/wsgi.py

ServerName localhost

Alias /media/ /home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server/static/
Alias /static/ /home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server/static/

<Directory /home/Webmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**So the problem is**, what is wrong with this? Why can't apache run this thing as it's supposed to.. If at all possible it would be truly epic with some cool terminal commandos that I can copy paste and then it's working like magic! =)

Any ideas to solve this would be really nice!

Answer (score 1):

You need to just add path of the location where you settings.py file is present and then set environment variable to `settings`. Make the following change to your wsgi files.

```
sys.path.append('/home/Wedmod/www/djangojquerycontroller/Server')
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"]="settings"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for tip buy actually I already have that in wsgi.py, but I used  `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Server.settings")` instead, tried your row now, but it didn't work. But the sys.path.append part is already done and if I print sys.path it looks good.

Comment: This still isn't solved.. Anyone  with some ideas what to try? Thanks